# Присвоить одному элементу значение из другого массива

Tags: python, массивы

При выполнении следующего кода

```
funcdata=[['11'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14'], ['15'], ['16']]  
masks=[ [0]*3 ]*4 
masks[0][0]=funcdata[0][0]
print(masks)
```

Я ожидаю получить

```
[['11', 0, 0], ['0', 0, 0], ['0', 0, 0], ['0', 0, 0]]
```

(присвоить одному элементу значение из другого массива) но получаю:

```
[['11', 0, 0], ['11', 0, 0], ['11', 0, 0], ['11', 0, 0]]
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы создаете массив вот таким образом:

```
masks=[ [0]*3 ]*4
```

Вы реально создаете массив из 4х элементов, который имеет 4 ссылки на один и тот же элемент. Это легко проверить вот таким образом

```
masks=[ [0]*3 ]*4 
print(masks)
print(id(masks[0]))
print(id(masks[1]))
print(id(masks[2]))
```

Вот результат:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
4567441352
4567441352
4567441352
```

Как вариант можно создать массив вот так:

```
funcdata=[['11'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14'], ['15'], ['16']]  
masks=[ [0]*3 for x in range(0,4)] 
print(masks)
print(id(masks[0]))
print(id(masks[1]))
print(id(masks[2]))
masks[0][0]=funcdata[0][0]
print(masks)
```

Результат будет:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
4567408328
4568289736
4567486856
[['11', 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
masks = [[0]*3]*4
```

Содержание вашей переменной  в памяти выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Cm. [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=masks%3D%5B%20%5B0%5D*3%20%5D*4&cumulative=false&curInstr=1&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).)

Как вы можете из картинки узнать, в памяти *только один* список `[0, 0, 0]`, а переменная `masks` является *списком четырех ссылок на его*.

Несмотря на то, с которой из этих 4 ссылок работаете, чтобы изменить первоначальный список `[0, 0, 0]`, *все эти ссылки будут показать на измененный список:*

```
masks[0][0] = funcdata[0][0]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]